# Prove $f(x)=1$ in almost everywhere $x\in \Omega$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space, $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an integrable function such that $\int f \, d\mu=1$ and $|f(x)| \leq 1$ in almost everywhere $x \in \Omega$. Prove $f(x)=1$ in almost everywhere $x\in \Omega$.
Any helps? I don't know how to use the hyphotesis $|f(x)| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer,
We define $h=1-\text{Re}(f)$. Then:
\begin{equation*}
\int hd\mu= \int (1-\text{Re}(f))d\mu= \mu(\Omega)-\text{Re} \int f d\mu = 1-1=0
\end{equation*}
Like $h\geq 0$ (beacuse $\text{Re }(f)\leq |f|\leq 1$), $h=0$ in almost everywhere. So, I conclude $\text{Re}(f)=1$ in almost everywhere. But, how can I conlude $f=1$?

Answer (score 1):

This answer continues your own answer. Since you where able to prove that $\operatorname{Re}(f)=1$ almost everywhere, it follows from the equatility
$$|f|^2=|\operatorname{Re}(f)|^2 + | \operatorname{Im}(f)|^2,$$
that $\operatorname{Im}(f) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 2$ call
$$\Omega_n= \{ x \in \Omega : f(x) \le  1- (1/n)\}$$
Then
$$1 = \int_{\Omega} f(x) dx = \int_{\Omega_n} f(x) dx + \int_{\Omega \setminus \Omega_n} f(x) dx \le \int_{\Omega_n} (1- (1/n)) dx + \int_{\Omega \setminus \Omega_n} 1 dx$$
Recall that in a probability space $$\mu (\Omega - \Omega_n) = 1- \mu (\Omega_n)$$ Hence
$$1 \le \int_{\Omega_n} (1- (1/n)) dx + \int_{\Omega \setminus \Omega_n} 1 dx = \mbox{computations} =1 - \frac{\mu ( \Omega_n)}{n} \le 1$$
This chain of inequalities show that for all $n$
$$\mu ( \Omega_n)=0$$
To conclude, note that
$$\{ x \in \Omega : f(x) <1\} = \bigcup_n \Omega_n$$
Hence, this set has measure zero.